# Am I using the correct jQuery syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code -

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1023) {
        for (var i = 0; i < seatInfo.length; i++) {
            if (seatInfo[i].data == 'true') {
                document.getElementById('Btn1').style.visibility = "visible";
                break;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('Btn1').style.visibility = "hidden";
            } 
        }
        if (nameInfo[0].data == "true") {
            document.getElementById('Btn2').style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
    if ($(window).width() <= 1022) {
        document.getElementById('Btn2').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
});
```

Is this is the correct way to write it? I notice that it contains a JavaScript and jQuery mix.

Comment: CSS Media queries! No JavaScript needed.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, then _use jQuery_. You have already paid the biggest price delivering the payload.  `$('#Btn2').css('visibility', 'hidden');` or better, `$('#Btn2').hide();`

Comment: He can't get `seatInfo` in CSS, though.

Comment: @the - good edit! Don't forget the title and the body though. You should try and address all issues a post has with one edit. Formatting, title and body.

Comment: well as you can see i need to use some data from a separated script file - that why i'm using in the code - seat[i].data - an so on.So how can i used it in jQuery?!

Comment: As a minor nitpick, can't you just use an else as opposed to a second if?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) from jquery and set it as json structure to define one or multiple CSS attributes, this is more easier for me to remember.

```
$('#Btn1').css({
    'property': 'value', 
    'property': 'value'
});
```

or just use it like this for a single attribute

```
var btn1 = $('#Btn1'),
   btn2 = $('#Btn2'),
   window = $(window); 

window.resize(function () {
    if (window.width() >= 1023) {
        for (var i = 0; i < seatInfo.length; i++) {
            if (seatInfo[i].data == 'true') {
                btn1.css('visibility','visible');
                break;
            } else {
                btn1.css('visibility','hidden');
            } 
        }
        if (nameInfo[0].data == "true") {
            btn2.css('visibility','visible');
        }
    }
    if (window.width() <= 1022) {
        btn2.css('visibility','hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: What i need to write in the css3 of, let's say btn2 - is it ok if i set it this way? - #btn2{visibilty:hidden} - because i have tried it and it seem like the button doesn't disappear when i set the page to a lower scale

Comment: not it is not do this instead $('#Btn2').css('visibility','hidden');

Comment: I'm downvoting this, because it contains no explanation of what has been changed and why, and inconsistently uses `.show()` in one place but `.css('visibility'...` in the others. As code, it's not bad, but as a useful answer for future visitors it is.

Comment: Removing downvote per edit, but a couple of nitpicks: 1) Referring to a Javascript object literal as "JSON" is stretching the definition somewhat - the syntax is the inspiration for JSON, but it's not really the same thing. 2) While knowing about `.css()` in general is useful, it's worth pointing out that it's unnecessarily verbose for this job, because you can just use `.show()` and `.hide()`.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are specifically asking about the jQuery syntax then the answer is no.** You are using the native JavaScript methods instead of the much shorter jQuery methods.

Take a look at some [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). For  instance:

An element with an id attribute of `foo` can be found using jQuery's [id attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) `#`:

```
var element = $( "#foo" ); // match the element
```

Changing an elements visibility attribute is the same as changing any other css attribute:

```
element.css( "visibility", "visible" ); // change css properties
```

A great feature of jQuery is it's many shortcut methods. There are a few shortcut method to display and hide elements (and toggle them):

- [`element.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
- [`element.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
- [`element.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 1):

Why stop using jQuery half-way?

- For `document.getElementById('Btn1')` use `$('#Btn1')`.
- For `.style.visibility = "visible"` use `.show()` (or, if you want to be very precise, `.css('visibility', 'visible')`)

There is [lots of good documentation on the official jQuery site](http://learn.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('#some-id').hide()` and `$('#some-id').show()`. Instead of `document.getElementById('some-id')` with `style.visibility = "visible"` or `style.visibility = "hidden"`.